# Pandas: Column medians based on column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, median

I have the following pandas DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,6), columns=['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3'])
df

           A1         A2          A3          B1          B2           B3
0   -0.409420   2.382457    1.151565    0.625461    0.224453    -0.351573
1   -0.676554   -1.485376   0.597227    0.240113    0.033963    1.224241
2   0.678698    1.392778    1.031625    0.388137    -0.566746   -0.798156
```

How do I get the median of the columns like this

```
        medA     medB
0        ...      ...
1        ...      ...
2        ...      ...
```

My actual data frame has 300 columns, so I would like to differentiate by similarity in column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this looks like `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),['A','B'],'index','idx')
  .groupby('index').median().add_prefix('med_').rename_axis(None))
```

Or `groupby` with the first string on `axis=1`

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str[0],axis=1).median().add_prefix('med_')
```

---

```
      med_A     med_B
0 -0.075465 -0.317335
1 -0.355822 -0.517270
2  0.279270 -1.134389
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a for loop answer:

```py
dict = {}
dff = pd.DataFrame()

for letter in ['A', 'B']:
    dict[letter] = []
    for col in df.columns:
        if col.startswith(letter):
            dict[letter].append(col)
    dff[f'med_{letter}'] = df[dict[letter]].median(axis=1)
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "to differentiate by similarity in column name", here it just compares the beginning of each column name with the entries in the primer list (`['A', 'B']`).